# azure claims based sign on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, authentication

I am working on a web app that will be deployed to azure. It uses claims-based single sign on to sign in users. However since the I am using a local development machine to create the app this is not available. Is there any way for me add a way for this to also work on my local machine?

I hope somebody can help!

Comment: What framework/tech are you using for the app (MVCx, ASP.net core?) and which sign on provider?

Comment: @RussellYoung asp.net 4.5 mvc web api. and azure ad.

Comment: I would probably look at writing an attribute that replaces Authorize, and instead checks for debug or dev mode before calling functionality for the real auth